# ItemProcessor/ItemWriter design when business logic is complex in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have the business(A ~ E) logic as below.

```
Search target -> A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

The search target will be implemented as ItemReader, Each business logic includes a corresponding persistence operation (DB write).

And <strike>all operations</strike> each operation(target) must be processed within one transaction.

In this case, how to design ItemProcessor and ItemWriter is efficient?

1. Create data for all business logic (all data for persistence from A to E) in ItemProcessor and only handle persistence in ItemWriter.
2. Handle business logic including persistence in ItemWriter without ItemProcessor.
   (Of course, I will create an object responsible for each business logic, and the ItemWriter will only call it.)

Comment: I am hoping this is an assignment from school you are hoping someone will do for you.    If this is an actual design it is designed to fail.   You never want your entire batch process to work under one transaction.    Why use transactions if you are going to do that??  If your process is working 800,000 rows and one insert fails you lose everything.

Comment: @BrianC Sorry. I wrote the question wrong.

As you said, all data must not be processed in one transaction.
Each data must be processed in one transaction.

If 800,000 data needs to be processed, a total of 800,000 transactions are created and processed.

Comment: @BrianC. What kind of schools give their students assignments with `Spring Framework` (particularly the `Spring-batch`) ? Lol.